# Microsoft equivalent of Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have heard positive things about Eclipse RCP (Rich Client Platform) - does Microsoft has similar plugin UI framework available?   I found an [article](http://ianskerrett.wordpress.com/2005/12/05/when-to-use-eclipse-rcp/) from the Eclipse.org marketing director where he states:

"An organization that is 100% Microsoft probably won't/shouldn't consider Eclipse RCP."

A colleague pointed out that this article was posted in 2005, so i was wondering if Microsoft has a competing product by now, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand after reading a quick description of Eclipse RCP, Microsoft's version of the product would be a stripped-down Visual Studio shell that you use as a starting point for your own app.

It turns out they do have a [product like that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685612.aspx), but it's not really intended for building apps other than custom IDEs.  Personally, I think this is a good thing.  Eclipse and Visual Studio are both rather heavy programs.  Even stripped down, I don't think they'd make s very good starting points.  I'm much happier using Windows Forms, WPF, or even Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Rich Client Platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform)

> While the Eclipse platform is designed
>   to serve as an open tools platform, it
>   is architected so that its components
>   could be used to build just about any
>   client application. The minimal set of
>   plug-ins needed to build a rich client
>   application is collectively known as
>   the Rich Client Platform.
>
> Applications other than IDEs can be
>   built using a subset of the platform.
>   These rich applications are still
>   based on a dynamic plug-in model, and
>   the UI is built using the same
>   toolkits and extension points. The
>   layout and function of the workbench
>   is under fine-grained control of the
>   plug-in developer in this case.

So I'm pretty sure the competition is the .Net platform itself.

Answer (score 0):

Although there might be some RCP frameworks for other languages, the RCP term (Rich Client Platform) has been coined mostly in the java world. There are only two important RCPs out there: Netbeans for Swing and Eclipse for SWT. The rest is negligible, too small communities to sustain development.

As a side note: Intellij Platform, the free base of all Intellij Products and also of Android Studio, is not RCP framework for generic applications (statemens for that are in Jetbrain's discussion archives from authors themselves. The under-the-hood API is not mature enough and has been not designed to be used for generic purpose RCP development). It is however usable for custom IDE development, as done by Google for Android Studio. There are also some licensing reasons of Intellij Platform holding back the future as a generic RCP framework.

You can also see that the RCP framework is always bound to some IDE of choice, as a base to build the final desktop product with it.

No there is nothing like RCP for Microsoft technology stack. The idea behind RCP is driven by the huge ecosytem of open source software, where multiple plugins from various vendors connect together to communicate over defined extension points and form a product. As Microsoft has been not involved in the open source in the beginnings and has been closed for the community, they had their own company-internal approach, but definitely not so sophisticated as Eclipse RCP, because there was no need for it. The design of Eclipse was not so nice in the beginnings, the sophistication comes as a result being public product used by the industry after nearly 20 years of existence. The design decisions are voted by Eclipse Foundation members such as IBM, RedHat, Oracle and others.